# OpenGL - easy way to change the value of a variable interactively

Tags: opengl

What I want is to be able to change the value of a variable through the window with the graphics, not from the code. It's ok if there are several fixed values and there is a choice only between them. Can you please give me some ideas?

I was thinking of something like this:
|--|--|--|--|--|, where each vertical line repesents a value and when you click the line, the value is changed, but it's a bit difficult for me to implement this. Any simpler ideas

Comment: Is keyboard input an option or are you trying to do this only with mouse input?

Comment: With keyboard is also an option. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick keyboard-based solution (I'm assuming C++):

Let's assume your values are all in an array called `values`:

```
const int NUM_VALUES = 5;
int values[NUM_VALUES];
```

Keep track of the selected value:

```
int selectionIndex = 0;
```

Make a function to handle key presses:

```
void keyPressed (unsigned char key, int x, int y) { 
    if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT) {
        if(--selectionIndex < 0)
            selectionIndex = NUM_VALUES - 1;
    } 
    else if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) {
        if(++selectionIndex >= NUM_VALUES)
            selectionIndex = 0;
    }  
    else if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP) {
        values[selectionIndex]++;
    }  
    else if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN) {
        values[selectionIndex]--;
    }   
}
```

Finally, in your initialization, link `keyPressed` to `glutKeyboardFunc`:

```
glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressed);
```

Comment: Can I ask you just one more thing - I made a similar function with a callback - `void GLFWCALL onKey( int key, int action )` and there I change two variables one for the coordinates of a cirlce and there other is a number which is then given as a value to another variable, which is responsible for the number of objects, drawn in a calllist. The problem is that when using the keyboard the coordinates move, but the number doesn't change and the number of objects drawn is always the same :( Any solution? :S

Comment: @Faery I'd have to see the code. You can always open a new question and I'd be happy to take a look :)

Comment: I'm affraid it's a bit long for here, can I send it somewhere else.

Comment: @Faery Just include only the relevant code. I've seen StackOverflow posts span several source files over a few hundred lines.

Answer (score 2):

Different keyboard inputs are probably the easiest way to achieve this. Just use a switch-statement to distinguish between the different possibilites and store the value inside a variable. If you need to access it from your shaders, use the value as a uniform.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools:anttweakbar - AntTweakBar that is a great and simple to use GUI library.

Basically it renders a window where you can easily place your variables.

Initialize this and simply add your variable:

```
float myFloat = 0.0f;
TwAddVarRW(myBar, "myFloat", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &myFloat, "min=-10.0 max=10.0 step=0.1");
```